# perform action on incoming mail

Tags: workflow, event-handlers, custom-actions, incoming-email

I need to perform simple decoding of .eml files and adding some contents from it to a list. I have already written the .eml decoding part and adding stuff from it to list, but i need to tell sharepoint to fire that action whenever an email is received. I have little experience in workflows and sharepoint events, could someone please point me in the right direction and tell me what is the best way for me to approach a problem like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach I would like you to try,

1. Configure Incoming email settings on a SharePoint library. There are many articles in the web, like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx) which explains the same.
2. Once you start receiving emails directly to SharePoint library, you can use the [SPEmailEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx) class which fires when an email is received in a list and then you can initiate a workflow or update a list item or whatever.